Extracted Game Model - Many Mask Textures
[Reference Question] SMITE model materials nodes
I am wondering about extracting SMITE models using Umodel. I am able to extract the models and apply the diffuse textures and some others that are obvious to the models. However, like my referenced question, there are a lot of mask1/mask2/gmask/dmask for each model. I do not know how to apply these, I assume most are for metalness or something but it doesn't seem to do much.
Is there a good way of determining what each one goes to, or does that come with just plugging each one into each part of the Principled BSDF and seeing what happens?
It is very tedious and I'm wondering if I'm doing something incorrectly.
How can you tell what each texture goes to, or how to use/apply them?
It seems in the answer of my referenced question, he played around with it and was able to figure it out. But most of the other models' textures have all kinds of differences so I am very unsure how to use them to make them look like the in-game model.
